# There are some method or function in Python 2.x that can form a list recognizing the comma which separate string elements?

Tags: python, string, list, methods

I'm trying to write a function that does something like this:

```
>>> Give-me the name of three famous American (use a comma to separate the names).
Benjamin Franklin, Thomas Jefferson, Carl Sagan
```

And put the given names into a list like this: ["Benjamin Franklin", "Thomas Jefferson", "Carl Sagan"] and NOT a list like this: ['Benjamin', 'Franklin,', 'Thomas', 'Jefferson,', 'Carl', 'Sagan'] as the split() method does.

There are (in Python 2.6) some method or function that can recognize the comma to form lists elements?

Comment: in addttion to the answers below you can use `strip()` to remove whitespace from the user input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`split`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method of the string also takes a separator as an optional argument.

```
>>> names = 'Benjamin Franklin, Thomas Jefferson, Carl Sagan'
>>> names.split(',')
['Benjamin Franklin', ' Thomas Jefferson', ' Carl Sagan']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> 'Benjamin Franklin, Thomas Jefferson, Carl Sagan'.split(', ')
['Benjamin Franklin', 'Thomas Jefferson', 'Carl Sagan']
```